# Splitting long error message

Tags: java, regex, split

I am currently trying to add a few errormessages to my application. For that I am using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);`
Basically everything is working as I'd expect it to. But one thing is a bit of a pain.
I am using `e.getMessage()` to receive the description of the occuring error.

In the case of a sql connection error this is such a long message, that it can't possibly fit to the screen. So I thouht to split it after every sentence, using `split([\\.])`.

This is working as well, BUT: the message includes a part like this
`Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out".`, which, of course ends up in:

```
Error: "java
net
SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out"
```

How could I avoid this behaviour? Or is there possibly a better way to achieve the result of a splitted error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just split on every space that has dot before it?

Try maybe `split("(?<=[.])\\s+")`

`(?<=[.])` is [positive-look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). It is used to make sure that group of spaces `\\s+` have dot before it, but will not include this dot in match, so it will stay untouched after split, while white-spaces will be removed.

Comment: Nice, that one has better logic to work at the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure until your input and expected result are posted in full, but you could use "lookarounds" for that purpose.

For instance:

```
String input = "Error: \"java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out\".";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("(?<!\\w)\\.(?!\\w)")));
```

**Output**

```
[Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out"]
```

**Explanation**

- It splits the `String` based on (escaped) dot `Patterns` neither preceded nor followed by any word character
- It prints the split `Array` (here, only 1 element since the package-delimiting dots do not match the `Pattern` as expected)

Comment: That's it, thank you! Basically a lookbehind was enough, since the additional lookahead would avoid a split at the end of "normal" sentences.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to use regexes is using [WordUtils.wrap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap%28java.lang.String%2C%20int%29) from the `apache.commons.lang` package. Using a regex has the advantage of not using an additional library, but makes the code a wee bit more unreadable. In your case not really a big issue, but as an added benefit, `commons.lang` contains a good deal of useful stuff which might come in handy in your project.

It is one of the libraries which is pretty much a constant in my tool-belt.